# Check every element of array of record is 0 in VHDL

Tags: arrays, record, vhdl

In VHDL, I have an array of a record. I want to do an if statement where I check that some element of that record is '0' at throughout every index of the array. How can I do this?
So if I have

```
type offset_t is record
 a : std_logic;
 b : std_logic;
end record

type offset_array is (7 downto 0) of offset_t;

type blah is record
 offset2 : offset_array;
end record
```

How can I check that the "a" element of `offset2(7 downto 0)` is `0`? What is the if statement?
I tried using `'range` and other ways, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: David, there is a pretty good answer by Martin Thompson. It would be polite to "accept" it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check only the `a` element, you'll have to iterate:

```
for i in a.offset2'range loop
   assert a.offset2(i).a = '0';
end loop;
```

If you want to check everything everywhere is zero, create a constant:

```
constant all_zeros : blah := (offset2 => (others => (others => '0')));
```

Then you can compare with it:

```
assert a = offset2;
```

Comment: Ok, but this creates ‘a.offset2'length‘ individual ‘assert‘ statements. You could rather define a function to implement your condition and then simply ‘assert mycheck(a);‘.

Answer (score 0):

Try `a.offset2 = (7 downto 0 => (a => '0', b => '0'));`.
You've made a few errors in your data type examples. The code below should work.

```
architecture RTL of demo is
    type offset_t is record
        a : std_logic;
        b : std_logic;
    end record;

    type offset_array is array (7 downto 0) of offset_t;
    type blah is record
        offset2 : offset_array;
    end record;
    signal a : blah;
begin
    a.offset2 <= (others => (a => '0', b => '0'));
    assert a.offset2 = (7 downto 0 => (a => '0', b => '0'));
end architecture RTL;
```

Comment: I don't want to assign everything to 0 though. I need to check if they are all 0, after some logic. Like if offset2(7 downto 0).a are all 0. Shouldn't it be offset2(i).a, where I have 8 elements of offset_t (each containing a and b)?

Comment: in that case, you will need to loop over all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion a function that you can easily plug in an if statement (look for     aElementOfOffset2IsZero).

```
architecture rtl of if_record_array_record is

    type offset_t is record 
        a : std_logic; 
        b : std_logic; 
    end record;

    type offset_array is array(7 downto 0) of offset_t;
    type blah is record 
        offset2 : offset_array; 
    end record;

    function aElementOfOffset2IsZero(
        record_array_record : blah
    ) return boolean is
    variable result : boolean := TRUE;
    begin
        for i in 0 to record_array_record.offset2'length loop
            if record_array_record.offset2(i).a = '1'  then
                result := FALSE;
            end if;

        end loop;

        return result;

    end function;

    signal ablah : blah;

begin  

    process
    begin
        --if statement you wanted
        if aElementOfOffset2IsZero( ablah ) then
            --...
        end if;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture rtl;
```